# RedirectToAction() generates wrong URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem with MVC 4, and I guess it's something really trivial, but it's been bugging me for the last day and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have this url:

```
http://www.example.com/my-dashed-url
```

I have a Controller named:

```
public class MyDashedUrlController: Controller
{
}
```

I have only two Routes like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute("my-dashed-url",
               "my-dashed-url/{action}",
               new { controller = "MyDashedUrl", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home",
                            action = "Index",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I get to the index just fine. However, when I do this:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (NoUserIsLoggedOn)
            return RedirectToAction("Logon", "MyDashedUrl");

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Logon()
    {
        Contact c = GetContact();

        return View(c);
    }
```

It doesn't redirect me to the "Logon" action properly.
It should redirect me to:

```
 http://www.example.com/my-dashed-url/logon
```

but instead it tries to redirect me to:

```
 http://www.example.com/logon
```

... which doesn't work (404 Not Found)

I'm missing something. Can anyone spot it? If anyone needs any more information, let me know.

And it's EVERY RedirectToAction that does the same thing in this controller. A Html.BeginForm("Logon", "MyDashedUrl") would also generate:
http://www.example.com/logon

I guess it has to do something with the Routes I defined, but I can't find the faulty one, seeing as they're all the same. If I disable all of my Routes besides the default one from MVC, the problem remains the same

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have declared this custom route **BEFORE** the default one:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "my-dashed-url",
        "my-dashed-url/{action}",
        new { controller = "MyDashedUrl", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Remember that routes are evaluated in the order you declared them. So the first route that matches a request will be used. If you declare your custom route after the default one, it is the default route that will match the request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately no joy, because my routes are already defined in this order. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: I have just tested this setup and it worked for me. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else. Can you reproduce this in a newly created application?